# I can't use plotly on python

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to reproduce an example from the plotly website in python. Here it is:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create random data with numpy
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

N = 100
random_x = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
random_y0 = np.random.randn(N) + 5
random_y1 = np.random.randn(N)
random_y2 = np.random.randn(N) - 5

fig = go.Figure()

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y0,
                    mode='markers',
                    name='markers'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y1,
                    mode='lines+markers',
                    name='lines+markers'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y2,
                    mode='lines',
                    name='lines'))

fig.show()
```

but it doesn't work. First I had this error:

```
----> 1 import plotly.graph_objects as go
      2 
      3 # Create random data with numpy
      4 import numpy as np
      5 np.random.seed(1)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.graph_objects'
```

so I tried `from plotly import graph_objs as go`  instead, just to obtain:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-320177ebffca> in <module>
     16 fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y0,
     17                     mode='markers',
---> 18                     name='markers'))
     19 fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y1,
     20                     mode='lines+markers',

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

It seems it must be `graph_objs` instead of `graph_objects` but the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`still appears...

Comment: have you done`pip install plotly` or `pip3 install plotly`?

Comment: I used ```pip install plotly``` before running the code. It seems that it is correctly installed (no error messages for pip install plotly), but I can't run the code. I'm using Jupyter notebook

Comment: which version of plotly are you using?

Comment: 2.7.0 . I can run other examples.

Comment: That is likely the root of the issue, there is a version `5.1.0` at the moment and the syntax has changed a lot since then. Simply upgrading your version should do the trick

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I though that the latest version was automatically installed/upgraded with ```pip install plotly```,  but I had to specify the version with ```pip install plotly==5.1.0```. Now the code works. Thanks for your help!